# Leaves sheds vs leaves falls off

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, poetic

Which is suitable to be more poetic???

- a leaf that sheds
- a leaf that falls off

Comment: Hi Anagha, welcome to EL&U. Proofreading questions (e.g. "Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the **[Tour]**. PS a tree sheds leaves but a leaf sheds water :-)

Comment: Whichever fits the metre of the poem.  "Sheds" is more idiomatic, but that's not the only consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the OP is asking which sentence of theirs is more poetic, I cannot answer. The title of the question is, however, ungrammatical.

- *leaves shed*
- *leaves fall off* (the trees)

But I can illustrate how the term "shed" should/can be used.

**Q:** What does a leaf shed?
**A:** Moisture? Clorophyll?

**Q:** What do trees shed?
**A:** If the trees are [deciduous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deciduoushttps://) then the answer is *leaves*

> **1** (of a tree or shrub) shedding its leaves annually.
>
> ‘*sun-loving deciduous trees like aspen*’

**Q:** What do tears shed? **A:** Saline?

**Q:** What do eyes shed? **A:** Tears

> **[shed tears](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shed_tears)**
> Weep; cry.
> *‘You would almost see the palm trees weeping and shedding tears.’*

Source: Oxford Dictionaries